# java - trying to catch exception from scanner in a loop

Tags: java

There is a 2d array called data that represent a matrix with l lines and c columns.
I want to save the matrix numbers with a scanner.

but when the user try to type 1.5 I want to catch the exepction, and ask the user for a new valid number, of course without continue to the next number.
I try this code. but when I type for example 1.5 , I got a flood "Please enter a valid integer number".

how Can I make it work right?

thank you for help :)

```
    for (int l=0;l<data.length;l++) {
        for (int c=0;c<data[0].length;) {
            try {
                int num = scanner.nextInt();

                data[l][c] = num;
                c++;
            }
            catch(RuntimeException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer number");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but try writing `scanner.nextLine();` after your printout in the catch-block.

Comment: The reason you're getting a flood of messages is because your inner loop never ends.

Comment: @Makoto He has `c++;` in his try-block.

Comment: @Gendarme:  And if the OP enters the *catch* block...what happens?

Comment: @Makoto The try block is executed again, but allegedly it doesn't ask him for a new int, instead it jumps to the catch-block again right away. I am guessing this is because he doesn't start a new line after reading his `nextInt()`.

Comment: Avoid try-catch if you can. It is better to use `hasNextDouble()` method and if next value is not double, consume it with `next()` and ask for new value. See duplicate (you may need to refresh this page to see it) for more information.

Comment: I solved it. if I write "Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);" above "int num..." it works fine. ( it was above the entire loop). thank you